# How to stop popup message on login after installing VideoCam Suite?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, dll

I recently bought a Panasonic SDR-H80 digital video camera and after installing the software that came on the CD (VideoCam Suite) I keep getting a popup message when I login to the computer.

The message is:

```
ArcCon.ac - System Error
The program can't start because MagCore.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

Well I've tried doing that and it didn't help. I can run VideoCam Suite fine, I just keep getting the silly error each time I login.

My computer is 1 month old and is running Windows 7 Professional 64bit.

What is the problem and how can I fix it? Failing that, how can I supress the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by determining what ArcCon.ac was. It is ArcSoft Connection Service. Downloading and installing the latest version of it stops the error.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that the camera simply comes with a rubbish driver - like so many devices on the market.

In future the best thing you can do (but not always available) is to go to device manager, right click on the device and do install driver then manually locate it. The device will then be accessible to the system without requiring any special software.

But, to fix your problem, download [Microsoft / Sysinternals Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and simply look for the program that is starting with your system and disable it. I cannot be more help as there isn't enough information as to the program name.

To locate it, you can download [Microsoft / Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and run it straight away without closing the box, then use the target tool/button to find the process that has launched the box, then you can disable it through Autoruns.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's not a driver problem. The device doesn't come with drivers, just software for processing the video.

Answer (score -1):

Instructions can be found here:
http://www.arcsoft.com/support/technical-assistant.html

> > Expand: How do I fully uninstall/reinstall ArcSoft product?

I had to kill two tasks running in TaskManager, then delete the common folder they were residing in in program files (x86) and appdata, as it describes in the link above.

[tried to add a picture with two processes Arcsoft*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REZr0.png)